# Auto Deletion (TTL) in Cloudant

Tags: cloudant

I have been looking up ways to setup expiration / auto deletion of a document in Cloudant. According to Cloudant documentation TTL is not available, Am I mistaken in this regard? If not, what are the best alternatives to auto deleting a record in Cloudant or should I look into some other noSQL alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not mistaken, Cloudant doesn't have a TTL feature, you could implement your own using a view and an external service that checks it.

So if you only wanted to be sure the document was deleted on the day that it expired, you could have a service that ran once a day which would read the view for documents expiring on that day, and issue delete requests as required.

Comment: Thank you.  I might need a different database than cloudant  because I need to specify TTL at time of document creation and then modify it later as needed. Once a day service is not an option since every document will have a different deletion time based on time of creation. 
I am now looking into DynamoDB and MongoDB